# Как правильно загрузить веб-проект на github.com

Tags: java, веб-программирование, git, github, tomcat

Добрый день. Создал веб-проект с применением технологий (**Tomcat, JDBC, JSP, Servlets, Maven** etc). Как правильно загружать проект на **github**?
Загружать ли контейнер **Томкат** или какие либо отдельные элементы? Как должен выглядеть репозиторий на **github**, название и т.д..

Comment: Название понятное вам и отражающее суть проекта. Если система сборки Maven, то достаточно файла pom.xml, папки src. Так же не забудьте про файл README.MD

Comment: загружайте только исходники, скрипты сборки (pom.xml) и то что нельзя получить из исходников.

Comment: на всякий случай спрошу, а вы случайно не про развертывание спрашивайте?

Comment: Первый комментарий действительно помог. С далека понимал, что выгружать контейнер и другие инструменты не логично, но все таки точно не знал. Спасибо за ответ!